# How to get json data from url

Tags: html, jquery, json

i have js code like this

```
var data = {
  "items": [
{
"src": "xxx",
"url": "xxx",
"ttl": "xxx%"
},
]};


$.each(data.items, function(i, f) {
  $('ul').append('<li class="scroll-nav"><a href="' + f.url + '"><img class="squareBig" src="' + f.src + '" download="' + f.ttl + '"></img></a></li>');
});
```

its work perfectly but i want replace var data ={xxx} with import url from github

i have try this code but not work :)

```
$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/lokal.json', data.items, function(i, f) {
  $('ul').append('<li class="scroll-nav"><a href="' + f.url + '"><img class="squareBig" src="' + f.src + '" download="' + f.ttl + '"></img></a></li>');
});
```

and this  is my  json

```
var data = {
  "items": [
{
"src": "https://xxx",
"url": "https://xxx",
"ttl": "METRO  TV"
}
]};
```

plzz help me

Comment: You will need to loop over the returned JSON from the call. Refer to the documentation and you can see : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Change `f.url` to `f.items[0].url` as you have an array of "items" between `data` and `url` - this assumes you only have one `item` given your attempt to use `f.url` - if you have more and want multiple `ul`s then you'll need to iterate the items array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.getJSON` incorrectly.

`.getJSON` will return `data` and you need to use that data to loop over and process.

Check this out: [.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Following code should work for you:

```
$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firzi15/stb21/main/lokal.json', function (data) {
  $.each(data.items, function(i, f) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="scroll-nav"><a href="' + f.url + '"><img class="squareBig" src="' + f.src + '" download="' + f.ttl + '"></img></a></li>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please mark this answer correct and close the question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

this is for you reference. you need to loop through items from your json data.
Demo https://jsbin.com/nicacux/edit?html,js,console,output

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://jsonblob.com/api/1049293810068373504', data.items, function(i, f) {

        $.each(i.items, function(j, v) {
            console.log(v, f);
            $('ul').append('<li class="scroll-nav">' + v.ttl + '<a href="' + f.url + '"><img class="squareBig" src="' + f.src + '" download="' + f.ttl + '"></img></a></li>');
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: not efficient but its work :)  thanks  bro